# Empty QuerySet in django-mysql JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-mysql

When I am executing

```py
ModelName.objects.filter(firstName__contains="MyName")
```

it returns an empty queryset but when I am executing it's SQL equivalent in `dbshell` it is fetching the rows perfectly.

```sql
select * from AppName_ModelName where firstName like '%MyName%';
```

I have constructed the sql query as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains)

Comment: What if you `print(ModelName.objects.filter(firstName__contains="MyName").query)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It returns a query object

Comment: compare the query with the query you wrote in the `dbshell`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How do I view the generated query? I am not quite aware as to how to use the query object

Comment: Use `str(...)` on the query object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS('AppName_ModelName'.'firstName', CAST("MyName" AS JSON))` This is what it is executing. Do you think there is a way to bypass this behaviour?

Comment: The `contains` for a JSON field works differently than for a `CharField`. What if you use `ModelName.objects.alias(foo=Cast('firstName', output_type=CharField())).(foo__contains="MyName")`, with `from django.db.models.functions import Cast` and `from django.db.models import CharField`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you specify what exactly is foo? I mean it is showing invalid syntax

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'alias'`

Comment: @DebutGoswami: you use Django before Django-3.2?, then it is `.annotate(...)` instead of `.alias(...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I am using Django 3.0. when using `annotate` it gives `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_type'`

Comment: and replace `output_type=...` with `output_field=...`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes this did work but it is returning all the rows. And `.(foo__contains="MyName")` part is giving error